# LightDM showing wrong version on Kinetic

Tags: unity, lightdm, display-manager

Ubuntu Kinetic, 22.10. (Will soon update to Lunar.) Originally 13.10, upgraded via LTS versions since: 13.10 -> 14.04 -> 16.04 -> 18.04 -> 20.04 -> 22.04.

I use Unity because I like it. This installation started out on Unity, I didn't add it. GNOME 3 is in there, added during the update to 18.04, but never normally used because I hate it.

I get the jumping calligraphic kudu wallpaper -- but at bottom left it says "Ubuntu 22.04" while actually I am running 22.10.

It's not anything in the config files. I say this with confidence because `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/` is empty.